# Why is my transaction still pending? Its been 72 hours!

Tags: transactions

I bought some BTC off a friend a few days ago, and I'm still waiting for the transaction to be confirmed.

https://blockchain.info/tx/90136a914ebcb15d236b21b1bcd48e0744b97868ae570b9b30d1359361fdccce

Its been 72 hours.. What can I do?

Comment: he tried to cheap out on the fees. have him zap it and do it over with an adequate fee.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx what does zap mean? Relatively new to btc and this is the first time I had this issue. As you can see the satoshi rate is very low so I'm afraid the transaction is going to be forgotten

Comment: with bitcoin core you run `bitcoind -zapwallettxes` and it rescans the blockchain to rebuild your wallet balance without any pending transactions. other wallets have other mechanisms.

Comment: So he has to download and install bitcoin core to do it? And does this cancel the transaction so he can resend it with a higher fee?

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx .

Comment: it's easier if he can fix it from the same wallet that sent the transaction. but if he can import the wallet into bitcoin core chances are it will import without the transaction and he can just send it again. did you read the link that Chak posted above? it has lots of good info.